# Trying to install mavlink using anaconda. I keep getting " UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:"

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, unsatisfiedlinkerror, mavlink

As you can see I am trying to install mavlink using Anaconda. My main goal is to use mavgraph to graph log files for a quadcopter I am working on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code from my terminal:

```
$ conda install -c brenda pymavlink
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - pymavlink
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I try to install pyforms in anaconda environment. Finally I could solve the problem by uninstalling the pyforms and PyQt5 packages. These packages are considered as site-packages by anaconda/python that are located in AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages. I suppose by uninstalling anaconda even completely, these site-packages will not be removed... So the solution is uninstall these packages manually after that you re-install anaconda. I use the commands below to uninstall them:

```
python -m pip uninstall pyforms-gui
python -m pip uninstall PyQt5
```